# echo what I inserted

Tags: cmd, echo

I want to write a batch program that can repeat the what I inserted, like echo.

> speak [what to speak]

So how can I do this using batch language **ONLY**?

Thank you for all answers.

(Window version : Windows 7 64-bit)

---

Well,now I know I can use this line:

> set what=%command:~6%
>   echo %what%

And that's all. Simple!

Comment: Do you want to use the word `speak` instead of `echo`?

Comment: Yes. That's what I wanna do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `set speak=echo` then type `%speak% Hello world!` it says "Hello world" is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

well, this would be a simple one-line-batch-file (named `speak.bat`):

```
@echo %*
```

It would not handle some special chars, but for plain text it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
set /p speak=What to speak? 
echo %speak%
```

Comment: No, that isn't what I want. I want to **DIRECTLY** output what the user inserted. However, thank you for your response. Can you give me the answer that I want?